# Check if an exception is a checked exception at runtime

Tags: java, exception, runtime, unchecked-exception

Is this the correct way to check if an exception is a checked exception at runtime?

```
public boolean isChecked(final Throwable e) {
    return !(RuntimeException.class.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass()) 
             || Error.class.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass()));
}
```

Comment: `e instanceof RuntimeException`?

Comment: Can you add some context to your question?  Perhaps the bigger question is whether or not you should be checking the exception, regardless of whether it be checked or unchecked.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I have a very odd compile time error that forces me handle a thrown `Exception` but not a thrown `SomeSubClassOfException` that is not a runtime exception. Its a part of a small personal tutorial code that i am writing to revisit exception handling in java

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  If you have a method declared with `throws Exception` or `throws Throwable`, change it to only throw exceptions it needs to throw.  Note that multiple specific exceptions are allowed in a `throws` clause.

Comment: It was an XY Problem, I took a break then got back to it and figured it out. I am not posting the context because it is useless but, ill leave the question because there is none like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess some condition like below will be enough

```
return !(e instanceof RuntimeException || e instanceof Error);
```

Comment: No need to guess: your condition is correct according to the Java Language Specification. *"The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are Throwable and all its subclasses other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses."* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1

Comment: @kaya3 thank you for clarifying. I had slight doubts about hierarchy and `Error`, but now it is clear

Comment: oh, i forgot about the 'instanceof' keyword.

Comment: @Sero well, if my answer helped you at some point, you can accept it, so the question will be closed :)